# Warning as unexpected await inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, async-await, promise

I know it is a repeated question but still I am writing my query

Issue as Unexpected `await` inside a loop

Below is my code

```
 const createChartPanel = async (data) => { 
   let panel = []
   let promises = []
   for (let a = 0.0; a < totalMacroFactorCount; a += /* increment */) {
       //some bunch code here

       let promise = addCharts(/* your arguments */).then(() => {
           panel.push(chartPanel)
       });
       promises.push(promise)
       a = parseFloat(a + 1).toFixed(1);
    }
    await Promise.all(promises)   // await for all promises to finish
    return panel;
}
```

Before **addChart** function gets completed **promises.push(promise)** is called, how should I called **promises.push(promise)** once **addChart** process is completed

```
const addCharts = async (data, chartTable, barColor, orangeBar, maroonBar, darkBlueBar, chartHeight, isFirstRow) => {
   // some code
    const maxHeight = _.maxBy(_.flatten(modifiedData), 'y');

    const promisesBenchmark = modifiedData.map(async (subArr, index) => {
        const currentChart = await getSVG(index % 2, subArr, isStrScore, maxHeight?.y);
        return currentChart;
    });
    const svgs = await Promise.all(promisesBenchmark);

    let nidx = 0;
    for (const svg of svgs) {
        chartTable[nidx + 1].table.body.push([{
            svg: svg, alignment: 'center', border: [false, false, false, true],
            borderColor: '#41ABE0', borderWidth: 0.5,
            width: chartWidth, height: chartHeight, fillColor: (nidx % 2 ? 'white' : '#f2f2f3')
        }]);
        nidx++;
    }
};
```

Here SVG image is not created completely in the addChart and hence creating the issue

Comment: Does `addCharts()` return a promise anyway?

Comment: You are returning `panel` which is defined in the `for` loop? That is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add async to your parent function

```
const yourFunc = async () => {
 for (let a = 0.0; a < totalMacroFactorCount; a++) {
  let panel=[]

  //some bunch code here
  await // yourcode

  await addCharts(scenarioNameLoop, tableBody[0],
        barColor, orangeBar, maroonBar, darkBlueBar, 
  chartBodyAndHeight.calculateChartHeight, a === 0);
  panel.push(chartPanel);
 }
}
```

also disable eslint error by adding

```
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
```

Comment: it is already added, updated my question

Comment: Actually it is working fine, it was a warning of eslint

Comment: If you don't need repose of promise inside loop you can try promise. which in in the first answer. we can save promise time with that method

Comment: Inner promise bring the svg image which is necessary to bind in the further with chartTable

Answer (score 4):

If you want multiple promises, created by loop (or other means) to be awaited, then you need to capture those promises into `Array` and then use `Promise.all` function.

For some action to take place after the promise has been resolved, you need to use `.then` method on said promise (or you can move it to separate async function where you await those two actions accordingly).

```js
const createChartPanel = async (data) => { 
   let panel = []
   let promises = []
   for (let a = 0.0; a < totalMacroFactorCount; a += /* increment */) {
       //some bunch code here

       let promise = addCharts(/* your arguments */).then(() => {
           panel.push(chartPanel)
       });
       promises.push(promise)
    }
    await Promise.all(promises)   // await for all promises to finish
    return panel;
}
```

Comment: I have checked and found that it is not completing the process of addCharts and it gets added in promises.push(promise)

Comment: can you please see the updated code, I have updated as you suggested, but it is not working

Comment: @Xtremcool I can, but the your code and further description is very unclear. It's hard to tell what you want to achieve and by what means.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a boilerplate, `Unexpected await inside a loop` is an `eslint` error (check [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop) for more infos on eslint).

Theoricaly, your code is right because Javascript can handle `await` inside "simple" loops. ([here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) and [here](https://plainenglish.io/blog/async-await-foreach) for more insights)

Comment: it is a node.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add an increment into your for loop.

```
for (let a = 0.0; a < totalMacroFactorCount; a++) {//Code}
```

Provide some more information pls to help you more properly you maybe can code a workaround but i need more information on what is going on to help you

Comment: Updated my question, sorry i miss to add full code

Comment: If you are requesting more information or you aren't providing a solution, write a comment instead. Not an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @nacho im new here wont happen again :)